# Can't find my wireless driver on ubuntu server

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, server

I install ubuntu server on my laptop / that before i used with ubuntu and on wireless /, but now i can't find my wireless driver. I try `lspci -nn -v`
and i only find this

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Limited NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b5] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [1025:0504]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at c0430000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Memory at c0440000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Expansion ROM at afb00000 [disabled] [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [48] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=5 Masked-
    Capabilities: [ac] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [13c] Device Serial Number 00-00-b8-70-f4-f4-04-5e
    Capabilities: [150] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [160] Virtual Channel
    Kernel driver in use: tg3
    Kernel modules: tg3
```

I find one more command `sudo lshw -C network` but when i run it i get

```
 *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetLink BCM57785 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0f0
       version: 10
       serial: b8:70:f4:f4:04:5e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=full firmware=sb ip=172.16.1.90 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:c0430000-c043ffff memory:c0440000-c044ffff memory:afb00000-afb007ff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:ea:af:1d
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

So can some one help me find it and tell me how can i connect yo my ssid with wpa2

Comment: Running `lspci` without arguments can you find a line without description? Please add that result. We may be able to find the chipset with the Vendor ID and Product ID [xxxx:xxxx] and then try to find an adequate driver.

Comment: Isn't this a virtual machine?

Comment: @CelticWarrior i post it like this because there are too much characters. http://pastebin.com/zutr0s5n

Comment: Based on the results it either doesn't exist, is disabled, is broken, is in the USB bus or other, or you're in a virtual machine as suggested by @chili555 in which case it doesn't matter.

Comment: @CelticWarrior thanks man :) i will try to fix it. You may post it as a answer if you want

Comment: I suggest you add the brand/model. For the rest, you're welcome, but I would like to add that you could have at least said a simple yes or no to the virtual machine question.